# Update data in edit window in JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm looking for a way to update the value in a field on the edit window based on clicking a checkbox in the edit window.

I can get it to change the value, but the edit window doesn't update.

I use this to change the value:

```
$("#Table" + id).jqGrid("setCell", selectedRowId, "DataPartnerName", "Hello");
```

The value ends up being changed in the actual grid, but the text field in the edit window stays the same and doesn't change until I close the window (not submit) and then reopen it. If I click submit, it goes back to the original value because it never changed in the field in the edit window.

Is there a way to get the edit window to update or possibly have it close and then reopen when the checkbox is checked?

Comment: What you mean with **edit window?** - is this jqGrid edit dialog form or this is a custom dialog. In all cases having the code will be helpfull

Comment: As far as I know, it is just the "standard" pop up window that jqGrid has when you click the edit button.

Comment: Please, post the full code in order to get idea what happen?